# What happens when I `sock.recv(..)` on more bytes than have been sent to me?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

Suppose I've connected to a server using a `socket`. I have called `sock.recv(1000)`, but the server has only sent me 500 bytes.

In my experiment, `sock.recv` returned after receiving the 500 bytes.

But will this *always* be the case?

Or is it possible for `sock.recv` to continue waiting for ever if the argument passed to it is larger than the amount of bytes it will ever receive?

Comment: it will wait for the specified timeout or until it reads the appropriate number of characters and return however many characters it has available

Comment: @JoranBeasley This is the comments section, an area designed for requesting clarification and for arguing with people. If you think you know the answer, please give it below (i.e. in the answer section) so that it may be peer reviewed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html):

> The maximum amount of data to be received at once is specified by `bufsize`.

It's the maximum allowed, not an amount to wait for.

There's an optional `flags` argument, whose meaning is the same as for the Unix [`recv(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) system call. One of the values there is:

> MSG_WAITALL (since Linux 2.2)
>                 This flag requests that the operation block until the full
>                 request is satisfied.  However, the call may still return less
>                 data than requested if a signal is caught, an error or
>                 disconnect occurs, or the next data to be received is of a
>                 different type than that returned.  This flag has no effect
>                 for datagram sockets.

So if you use this option, it will wait until 1000 bytes are received, unless the connection is closed first.

Without the option, it waits until anything is available, and then returns it, up to the `bufsize` specified.

Comment: And the moral of the story, as ever, is _read the documentation_.

Comment: So if I don't use this option, it will wait until the bytes are received *or* until the timeout?

Comment: No, the option makes it wait, it normally doesn't wait.

Comment: It normally returns whatever is available, as soon as anything is available.